# T-SQL progressive numbering partitions

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, partitioning, ranking

I am aiming to obtain a record set like this

```
date   flag   number
01     0      1
02     0      1
03     1      2
04     1      2
05     1      2
06     0      3
07     1      4
08     1      4
```

I start from the record set with "date" and "flag" only. I am trying to compute the "number" column by using T-SQL ranking and partitioning functions.

A normal ranking would give a result like this:

```
 date   flag   number
    01     0      1
    02     0      1
    03     1      2
    04     1      2
    05     1      2
    06     0      1
    07     1      2
    08     1      2
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [date] CHAR(2)
   ,[flag] BIT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([date], [flag])
VALUES ('01', 0)
      ,('02', 0)
      ,('03', 1)
      ,('04', 1)
      ,('05', 1)
      ,('06', 0)
      ,('07', 1)
      ,('08', 1);

WITH DataSource ([date], [flag], [number]) AS
(
    SELECT [date]
          ,[flag]
          ,IIF(LAG([flag], 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [date]) = [flag], 0, 1) 
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT [date]
      ,[flag]
      ,SUM([number]) OVER (ORDER BY [date] ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS [number]
FROM DataSource
ORDER BY [date], [flag];
```

[image]

The idea is to check when group is changed using the `LAG` function:

```
IIF(LAG([flag], 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY [date]) = [flag], 0, 1)
```

Then, using the `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` to `SUM` group changes.

Answer (score 1):

j,

SQL Server 2012 has a number of new functions for example [SQL Lead()](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lead-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-next-value.aspx) and SQL Lag() functions. You can use the [SQL Server Lag() function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/lead-function-in-sql-server-2012-for-next-value.aspx) for the solution of your requirement

Here is my solution

```
with cte as (
select 
    date, flag, 
    LAG(flag, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY date) AS preVal,
    case when flag = ISNULL( ( LAG(flag, 1, NULL) OVER (ORDER BY date) ), flag) then 0 else 1 end as i
from recordset
)
select
    cte.date,
    cte.flag,
    sum(cte2.i)+1 r
from cte
inner join cte as cte2 on cte.date >= cte2.date
group by cte.date, cte.flag
order by cte.date
```

Comment: your solution is good and working, thank you.
I preferred gotqn's one because it is more linear thus readable, and he uses the rows/range option clause of the OVER BY command.

Comment: no problem :) I also learnt the "BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW" option which is better to continue with

Answer (score 0):

You could populate it in a cursor like this:

```
DECLARE  @Table TABLE (
[Date] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[flag] [int] NULL,
[Number] [int] NULL
) 

DECLARE @Date nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @flag int
DECLARE @number int
DECLARE @flagnumber int
DECLARE @flagincrement int

DECLARE  MyCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT [Date],FLag
FROM [LegOgSpass].[dbo].[testflag]
Order by [Date]

OPEN MyCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor
INTO @Date,@flag

IF (@@FETCH_STATUS>=0)
BEGIN

SET @number = 1
SET @flagincrement = @flag

INSERT INTO @Table ([Date],[Flag],[Number])
VALUES(@Date,@flag,@number)

FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Date,@flag
END
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-1)
BEGIN
IF (@@FETCH_STATUS<>-2)
IF @flagincrement = @flag 
SET @number = @number 

ELSE
SET @number = @number+1
SET @flagincrement = @flag

INSERT INTO @Table ([Date],[Flag],[Number])
VALUES(@Date,@flag,@number)
FETCH NEXT FROM MyCursor INTO @Date,@flag
END

CLOSE MyCursor
DEALLOCATE MyCursor

SELECT * FROM @Table
```

Comment: Your solution is acceptable, thank you, but I am trying to avoid cursors and iterations: I am updating the question.

Comment: I know, i just wanted to give an example- Glad you got it to work :)